# Passing Authenticated Users to SendBird from Django Rest Framework

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, sendbird

I have a Django DRF serving APIs and an Angular front end for a solution I am developing. I want to integrate SendBird Chat API into the application to allow authenticated users to chat to each other.

SendBird has a JavaScript API which I can use, but my query is how are my authenticated user details passed to SendGrid, e.g. if user X logins into website and user Y logs into website - how do I allow them to talk to each other.

I am pretty sure I've misunderstood something around sessions but any help is appreciated.

I am not looking for a specific code answer but a general architectural answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process to pass your user's details to SendBird should follow these steps:

- Create a SendBird user account via the Platform API when your user signs up on your service.
- Save the access token to your secured persistent store.
- Load the access token in your client and pass it to the SendBird login method.
- Periodically update your access token by issuing a new token to replace the previous one.

You can find more details about it [here.](https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript/authentication#3_connect_to_sendbird_server_with_a_user_id_and_an_access_token)

Comment: Thanks, it was in the documentation - completely missed it when I posted the question